# adwords API adparam to set price in ad

Tags: google-ads-api

I've been using the API for several things, and recently wanted to use it to set the prices displayed on my ads.

The adGroups are arraigned so that they are each related to a product. I simply want to update the param1 value in all ads in a given adGroup.

What I have found so far is that the parameter needs to be set for every single keyword used on that adGroup. The only usage I can see for this is to use more API calls/credits?

Recap on what I want to do:
Best case: Send the AdGroup ID up and a value for the param and have all ads up dated.
Worst Case: Send up the Adgroup ID and Ad ID and param Value for each ad to be updated.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ad params are tied to keywords, so there's no way right now to achieve what you are trying to do in a single call.

Comment: Is this planned for a future release? (According to the docs for the latest version (v201309) this still hasn't changed and multiple calls must be made.)